# Bash history expansion not working in script, even with set -H

Tags: bash

I'd like to use `!!` and other Bash history expansion features in a script. From what I understand, `set -H` should allow that. However, it doesn't seem to enable history expansion. Items like `!!` and `!-1` still don't work.

Here's a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -H

# These don't make it work either
set +f
shopt -s extglob
shopt histexpand  # This option does not exist

echo $-  # Settings are hBH

# These print literal '!' text, not history-expanded text
echo !-1
echo !!
```

Comment: You need `set -o history` so it will save history. Otherwise there's nothing for it to expand to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a non-interactive shell, you must specifically also enable command history:

```
set -o history
set -o histexpand
```

Source: [History expansion in scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/502443/74329)